# What does content: "."; in css do? It appears to act like clear:both and/or display:block by iteself

Tags: css, magento

In the standard Magento stylesheet there are a ton of css classes followed by

```
{
    clear: both;
    content:".";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

To test what it does I deleted the line and on at least one block it moved all of the content up by about 300px and allowed for floats everywhere. This is when I delete JUST the content:"." line.
It almost seems like it's acting as a display:block or clear:both - or working with them.

I have no idea what it does - can someone enlighten me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This block of style is called `clear fix`.
When a containing element in the page, a div, for example, contains only floating elements, it will collapse because the floating elements are removed from the page-flow.
This will cause the containing element to loose its' height.

What the clear fix does, is insert a non-meaningful content, a dot in most cases, using the CSS pseudo class `:after` and hides by setting the height to 0. This will force the containing element to self-clear itself and it won't loose its' height.

Read more about it here:
[css-tricks clear fix explained](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Comment: Thank you, very well explained.